# SearchView and BackPress event handling

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview, onbackpressed

I have include `SearchView` in the `HomeScreen` . I use `SearchView` for place search. This is my screenshot of `HomeScreen`:
[image]

This is my code in `onCreateOptionsMenu` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search_places);
    searchItem.setIcon(FontIconDrawable.inflate(getContext(), R.xml.ic_search));
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    placesSearchAdapter = new PlacesSearchAdapter(this.getContext());
    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(placesSearchAdapter);
    searchView.setMaxWidth(750);
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            corLDriveInfoContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fabDrivingDirection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mapView.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

This is my `SearchView` when I click on `SearchIcon`.
[image]

This is my `SearchView` result:

C.[image]

I have `FabButton` to drive the selected position.

D.[image]

But, my problem is, How do go back to `View C` from `View D` when I press back button?

Answer (score 1):

You should override `onBackPressed` method in your activity like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed();
   //change your View from D to C using the same code you used to go to D from C
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I include this to solve my problem in `onBackPress` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     searchItem.expandActionView();
     searchView.setQuery("", false);
     searchView.clearFocus();

  super.onBackPressed();
}
```